# Compiler warning about "implicit declaration" despite the function body already being defined

Tags: c, implicit

I wanted to create a ASCII Converter to GameBoy tile Numbers

I first had the Functions in another file, so I tried moving them into the same file where the functions have been used. I didn't know what to try next so I turned back here.

```c
#include <gb/gb.h>
#include <gb/font.h>
#include "../tiles/WindowMap.c"

#define ASCII_0 0x02
#define ASCII_1 0x03
#define ASCII_2 0x03
#define ASCII_3 0x03
#define ASCII_4 0x03
#define ASCII_5 0x03
#define ASCII_6 0x03
#define ASCII_7 0x03
#define ASCII_8 0x03
#define ASCII_9 0x03
#define ASCII_A 0x03
#define ASCII_B 0x03
#define ASCII_C 0x03
#define ASCII_D 0x03
#define ASCII_E 0x03
#define ASCII_F 0x03
#define ASCII_G 0x03
#define ASCII_H 0x03
#define ASCII_I 0x03
#define ASCII_J 0x03
#define ASCII_K 0x03
#define ASCII_L 0x03
#define ASCII_M 0x03
#define ASCII_N 0x03
#define ASCII_O 0x03
#define ASCII_P 0x03
#define ASCII_Q 0x03
#define ASCII_R 0x03
#define ASCII_S 0x03
#define ASCII_T 0x03
#define ASCII_U 0x03
#define ASCII_V 0x03
#define ASCII_W 0x03
#define ASCII_X 0x03
#define ASCII_Y 0x03
#define ASCII_Z 0x03

unsigned char Char_to_GBSCII(unsigned char character){   
    switch(character){
            case 'A': return ASCII_A;
            case 'B': return ASCII_B;
            case 'C': return ASCII_C;
            case 'D': return ASCII_D;
            case 'E': return ASCII_E;
            case 'F': return ASCII_F;
            case 'G': return ASCII_G;
            case 'H': return ASCII_H;
            case 'I': return ASCII_I;
            case 'J': return ASCII_J;
            case 'K': return ASCII_K;
            case 'L': return ASCII_L;
            case 'M': return ASCII_M;
            case 'N': return ASCII_N;
            case 'O': return ASCII_O;
            case 'P': return ASCII_P;
            case 'Q': return ASCII_Q;
            case 'R': return ASCII_R;
            case 'S': return ASCII_S;
            case 'T': return ASCII_T;
            case 'U': return ASCII_U;
            case 'V': return ASCII_V;
            case 'W': return ASCII_W;
            case 'X': return ASCII_X;
            case 'Y': return ASCII_Y;
            case 'Z': return ASCII_Z;
            case '1': return ASCII_1;
            case '2': return ASCII_2;
            case '3': return ASCII_3;
            case '4': return ASCII_4;
            case '5': return ASCII_5;
            case '6': return ASCII_6;
            case '7': return ASCII_7;
            case '8': return ASCII_8;
            case '9': return ASCII_9;
            case '0': return ASCII_0;
        }
}
unsigned char* String_To_GBSCII(const char* message){
    unsigned char r[20];
    r[0] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[1] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[2] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[3] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[4] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[5] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[6] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[7] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[8] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[9] =  Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[10] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[11] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[12] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[13] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[14] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[15] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[16] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[17] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[18] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[19] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    r[20] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);
    return r;
}


void PauseMenu(){

    unsigned char* PauseMessage = String_to_GBSCII("GAME PAUSED");
    set_win_tiles(0,0,5,1,PauseMessage);
    SHOW_BKG;
}
```

```
G:\GameBoy Game\Code>lcc.exe -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -DUSE_SFR_FOR_REG -c -o build/main.o main.c
GUIElements/PauseMenu.c(111):warning *** function 'String_to_GBSCII' implicit declaration
GUIElements/PauseMenu.c(111):warning *** function 'String_to_GBSCII' implicit declaration

G:\GameBoy Game\Code>lcc -Wa-l -Wl-m -Wl-j -DUSE_SFR_FOR_REG -o build/main.gb build/main.o

?ASlink-Warning-Undefined Global String_to_GBSCII referenced by module lcc84840
```

This is what i get by the LCC Compiler for GameBoy Games provided by the GameBoy Development Kit. Any Help would be very Appreciated.

Comment: Not even looking at the issue you're describing, there are a number of issues with the code. All of the `ASCII_<char>` have the same value, you use index 0 in every `Char_to_GBSCII(message[0])`, and worst of all, `String_To_GBSCII` return a pointer to a local variable, which is not something valid that can be done.

Comment: You are calling the Char_to_GBSCII function which accepts an unsigned char as input but you have a char as parameter inside String_to_GBSCII. You have also an undefined behaviour because you are returning a pointer to a local variable

Comment: @madduci Those type conversions are well defined.

Comment: `r[20] = Char_to_GBSCII(message[0]);` accesses out of bounds array `r`. Obviously `String_to_GBSCII` and `String_To_GBSCII` differ. You didn't define `String_to_GBSCII` function and compiler is correctly warning you. My subjective tip: just stick to pure snake case, lowercase only with underscores. And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you define the function

```
unsigned char* String_To_GBSCII(const char* message)
```

This is how you call it

```
               String_to_GBSCII
```

Note the difference in `t` and `T`.

If the compiler says that "functionA" does not exist, but you are looking at what you believe to be the definition, thinking "But there it IS!", then it is time to use the search feature of your editor, to test whether what the compiler misses is letter by letter what you are looking at.

Comment: I just noticed it is basically pointed out in @KamilCuk comment. Let me know if you claim the answer, then I will delete. But with your comment and the close votes the question is going to be closed and deleted as typo anyway.

Comment: Yeah i realized it now Too. I Fixed it now. Thanks for the Help!